# Gronwall-type inequality in higher dimension

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, gronwall-type-inequality

I would like to know if there is any kind of Gronwall inequality for a smooth function $u \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying 
$$
|\nabla u | \le K u,
$$
where $K$ is a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, fix $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the one-dimensional function $g(t)=u(tx)$. Then $g'(t)=\nabla u(tx)\cdot x$ and so
$$|g'(t)|\le Kg(t)|x|.$$
Now you can apply Gronwall to $g$. You will get $K|x|$ in the exponential.